# How to do PascalVoc evaluation with google object detection api

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, object-detection

I'm working with the new [Google object_detection api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) on my own dataset
In the config file there are fields `eval_config` and `eval_input_reader`, but I don't understand how to make them work.

I've also found a file in tensorflow/models/object_detection/ the file `eval.py` which seems to run the evaluation but I don't entirely understand what these args are:

```
 ./eval \
        --logtostderr \
        --checkpoint_dir=path/to/checkpoint_dir \
        --eval_dir=path/to/eval_dir \
        --pipeline_config_path=pipeline_config.pbtxt
```

Suppose I have a model checkpoint (3 ckpt files meta, index and data) what should I do with them?

Answer (score 0):

i am looking for a config file too, or any information on how to build one,  with parameters explanation, on this point the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md) is not really helpful

Comment: there are some examples at object_detection/samples/configs.
If you have a pascal format dataset (with images, corresponding annotations and imagesets) you can generate a .record file by something similar to object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py. 
You have to also generate a label_map.pbtxt (similar to what you would find in object_detection/data)
Then you put these paths to a config file (same kind as object_detection/samples/configs).

Still didn't manage to run the eval.py , though. It somehow get stuck and doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to to anything with the eval config field, but you should change the eval_input_reader.tf_record_input_reader.input_path field to point to your validation dataset, and the eval_input_reader.label_map_path should point to your label map.

Replace the `PATH_TO_YOUR_TF_RECORD` and `PATH_TO_YOUR_LABEL_MAP` strings in the sample config below.

```
    eval_config: {
    }

```
eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "PATH_TO_YOUR_TF_RECORD"
  }
  label_map_path: "PATH_TO_YOUR_LABEL_MAP"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

```

Comment: thank you I managed to make it work.
However could you explain, why I should not shuffle my dataset, it seems like it would always take the same images (they are ordered by labels in my case).
And what is the `num_readers` field?